# How to listen to a typing stop on the keyboard

Tags: android

I need to search somthing when user stop typing. How can I listen when user stop typing.
`doAfterTextChanged` works vey bad. The interval between stop and search must be less than a second.

Comment: _`doAfterTextChanged` works very bad_ Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @mcy the interval between typing stop and action is very short

Comment: Why you dont use {onTextChanged} then if you need faster response?